# Python Paramiko Permission denied

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Trying to execute commands on remote host via Paramiko:

```
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname=host,  port=int(port), username=username, password=password) 
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(cmd, timeout=60)
```

For "simple" commands like 'top', 'ls -la', 'uname', etc ... all works fine.
But for password asking commands like 'scp', I got the error (via Paramiko stderr):

> Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
>
> lost connection

even when trying to use the Paramiko 'stdin' object for input parameters:

```
stdin.write("myrootpasswd\n")
stdin.flush()
```

Comment: Look into the [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library, it's an "autoit/autohotkey"-like for command line.

Comment: @pynexj Haven't tried yet. I will let you know.